# jQuery - I am not getting the right child

Tags: jquery, parent-child, css-selectors

So I am trying to fake a `.click()` event on the first `<a>` within `.glossNav` within a specific `.words` when I click a `.letter`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(".letter").click(function(){
    var whichLetter = $(this).children("span").text();
    var selectedGloss = "#glossary-" + whichLetter;

    $(".words").fadeOut(200);
    $('.letter').removeClass('underline');

    $(selectedGloss).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    $(this).addClass('underline');

      if($(selectedGloss).children(".glossNav").length > 0) // There isn't always a nav.
      {
            alert("Yippee!");
            $(selectedGloss).children(".glossNav").first().click();
      }
});
```

The "Yippee!" is successfully alerting.

Here is my nav HTML (this is a glossary im building):

```
<div id="modelglossary"><div class="letterBar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-A">
        <span>A</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-B">
        <span>B</span>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="letter" id="selector-C">
        <span>C</span>
    </a>
.... and so on
</div>
```

Here is the bulk of the HTML:

```
<div class="words" id="glossary-S">
    <div id="s-page-1" class="glossPage">
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Zedcard</strong> - See <a class="wordRef" href="javascript:void(0)">Composite Card</a>.
        </span>
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Senior model</strong> - A senior model is a professional model in his 40s/50s/60s. As the average age is constantly rising, the advertisements go back more and more to older models to approach their target group. A senior model often has a good book as they can show a lot of experience or after easily being booked for ads they get publications from the beginning on.
        </span>
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Set</strong> - This is where the action of shoot takes place usually within a professional studio or within a location. It includes all the elements which make the shoot; for example the lighting, camera, art direction and art directed scenery.
        </span>
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Shooting</strong> - Shooting in general means the implementation of photo or film shoots.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="s-page-2" class="glossPage">
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Stock Photos</strong> - Stock photography is the supply of photographs licensed for specific uses. It is used to fulfill the needs of creative assignments instead of hiring a photographer. Today, stock images are usually presented in searchable online databases, where they are then purchased and delivered online. Often, they are produced in studios using a wide variety of models posing as professionals, stereotypes, expressing stereotypical emotions and gesticulations or involving pets.
        </span>
        <span class="glossBlock">
            <strong>Stylist</strong> - The stylist is in charge of the outfit of the model and discussing at length with the photographer or director, about theme of the shoot.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="glossNav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" page="s-page-1">1</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" page="s-page-2">2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: `$(selectedGloss).children(".glossNav").first().click();` isnt working. I have also tried `$(selectedGloss).children(".glossNav a").first().click();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your missing `a` in your selector. Because `.glossNav` is a div not an `<a>`..

Like this: `$(selectedGloss).find(".glossNav a").first().click();`

You should use `.find()` instead of `.children()` because it only select direct child element, and that is not in your case.. :)

See my edit..

Comment: That didnt work. I have selectedGloss fading in over 200ms, do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Where is your `Edit` @NixR.Eyes?

Comment: Just to point it out: there is no need to use first() *or* find() as selectedGloss isn't a selected DOM element to start with -- it's only a selector string. Just change the selector to this:

$(selectedGloss + ">.glossNav a").first().click()

Answer (score 0):

You're using .first() incorrectly. If your if statement is correct, then:

```
$(selectedGloss).children(".glossNav").first().click();
```

Is going to trigger the click event on the first *glossNav* class that is a child of the selectedGloss selector, not the first anchor within it. What you want to use is this to select the first anchor as well as select the glossNav from multiple levels deep.

```
if ($(selectedGloss + ">.glossNav").length > 0) {
    $(selectedGloss + ">.glossNav a").first().click();
}
```

Comment: That didnt work. I have selectedGloss fading in over 200ms, do you think that is the problem?

Comment: No but it's difficult for us to reproduce this issue with incomplete code -- your HTML has nothing with the class 'letter'. Can you make a jsFiddle showing the problem?